# Filter in dataGridview using Entity framework by textbox

Tags: c#, search, datagridview, entity-framework-6

this Code is Work fine Search Name

```
            if (chbxSearch.Checked)
            {
                dgvadministration.DataSource = db.SalesNames.Where(n => n.Name.Contains(txtName.Text)).ToList();

            };
```

but this Code not working  because  column Code as int
What do I do until it works

```
            if (chbxSearch.Checked)
            {
                dgvadministration.DataSource = db.SalesNames.Where(n => n.Code.Contains(txtCode.Text)).ToList();
            };
```

Class SalesName

```
        public int Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
```

Erorr

'int' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Contains(IQueryable, string)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable'

Comment: What does this txtName.text contain,string or integer?

Comment: Use n.Code.ToString().Contains...

Comment: n.Code.ToString().Contains
it's Working Thank U Pro